# Difficulty in upgrading 2.5 to 3.4

Tags: upgrade

I have fairly large 50 page web site built on Joomla 2.5 which I want to upgrade to 3.4 to enhance security. Our web developer states that the change from 2.5 to 3.4 requires the site to practically be rebuilt and it is not an easy click over as from 2.5 to 3.1 .  Does 30 hours to convert sound right?

Comment: Very hard to tell, see Lodders answer. This question will probably get closed. But I just want to add that the upgrade from 2.5 to 3.4 is most likely as easy as from 2.5 to 3.1.

Comment: I have worked on upgrades that took only a couple hours and upgrades that required week$$$$ to complete.

Answer (score 1):

How long's a piece of string?

A lot of factors you need to take into consideration, such as:

- How many extensions are you using?
- Are the extensions you're using Joomla 3.x compatible?
- Do you have any custom build extensions that are using deprecated code?
- How  experienced is your developer with Joomla?

Due to the factors, nobody here can give you even a rough estimate.

I'd suggest taking a copy of your Joomla 2.5 site, put it on either a sub-domain or local-host, perform the migration to 3.x, then go through each extensions individually to ensure they work correctly.

You'd better hope your developer did not start editing core Joomla file or did not follow Joomla coding standards/methods, else it will increase that time by quite a substantial amount